# How to interact with 360 moving video with Unreal Engine VR?

Tags: 360-virtual-reality

We need to interact with a 360 video using a VR headset, using Unreal Engine (not closed for Unity 3D though). The video is recorded in motion in a straight line.

The user, wearing a VR headset can:

- Move in one direction only, meaning backward or forward in the video
- Point to key parts of the video. Example pointing to a bottle on a table in the video will increase a value

In order to do so we are thinking about:

- projecting the video in the inside of a UV sphere. When the user goes forward or backward, the video will move frame by frame in the correct direction.
- creating a model of scene with the objects we want to interact with. When the user click in the direction of the bottle, she actually clicks on an "invisible" 3D bottle object even if it looks like a video for her.

In short the user would *only* see a frame to frame 360° video. But can interact with cleverly positioned objects around him, perfectly synchronized with what the user can see on the video.

Is there any easier way to solve this problem with Unreal/Unity ?

EDIT:

- [Related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvSwya5G2eI) demo by Unity in May 2017

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would be considered the easiest solution to problem. Maybe build a nice animation system, where you could add objects that appear at a certain timestamp, in a certain place and maybe move with the camera view and disappear at another timestamp.

Moving the user forward/backward in time can be done when it is a sitting VR experience. Standing will most definitely make some people fall over.

Another way would be to make a video-edit of an animated clickmap and play that in sync with the video. When the user clicks, you cast a ray to the animated clickmap and look up what action to perform, looking at the color.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Thank you. If this answers your question: Could you please mark the answer? This marks your question as resolved.

Comment: It is still an open question for me, I was expecting to be pointed to another direction. I will mark it as solved next week if there's still no answer. I hope that is ok with SO rules.